Как НЕ наследовать блок в дочернем шаблоне в Django
задаю вопрос по обучению Django. Делаю всё по видеоуроку, но решил немного отойти от этого курса и немного подправить страницу под себя.
Нашел такую проблему, что в одном шаблоне мне не нужно отображать блок с категориями в дочернем шаблоне
Вот так выглядит фрагмент файла base.html с блоком sidebar:
<!doctype html>

{% load static %}
{% load cache %}
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
</html>

<body>

{% include 'inc/_nav.html' %}

<div class="container mt-3">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <!--sidebar-->
            {% cache 60 sidebar %}
            {% block sidebar %}SIDEBAR{% endblock %}
            {% endcache %}
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

вот, собственно, сам файл сайдбара:
{% load news_tags %}

{% comment %}
<div class="list-group">
    {% get_categories as categories %}
    {% for item in categories %}
    <a href="{% url 'category' item.pk %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">{{ item.title }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endcomment %}

{% show_categories %}


Допустим, у меня есть дочерний от base.html шаблон, в котором я хочу оставить только форму, без того самого сайдбара:
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Обратная связь | {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
{% include 'inc/_sidebar.html' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Обратная связь</h1>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}


Я знаю, что можно убрать содержимое, но мне нужно убрать именно блок, который занимает определенное место на странице. То есть если смотреть, то сначала идет блок сайдбара (примерно 30% от страницы), а далее уже содержимое
Подскажите как я могу решить эту проблему. В документации не нашел ничего по этому поводу. Можно ли это сделать или нужно создавать новый базовый шаблон?

забыл упомянуть, что я знаю, что можно убрать содержимое, но мне нужно убрать именно блок, который занимает определенное место на странице. То есть если смотреть, то сначала идет блок сайдбара (примерно 30% от страницы), а далее уже содержимое

Дополнения вносите прямо в свой вопрос - вы можете его редактировать.

Переобъявите блок с таким же именем в вашем темплейте и оставьте его пустым.

пытался сделать это. На этом месте остаётся пустой блок, который оставляет стили

Ну значит переорганизуйте блоки в шаблоне так, чтобы убирание содержимого убирало и этот самый блок со стилями

Если что, блоки можно вкладывать друг в друга, то есть написать что-то вроде {% block sidebar_full %}<div class="col-md-3">{% block sidebar %} [...] (правда, не знаю, как тут будет вести себя cache)
